# Interval of a transformation of a uniform variable

Tags: random-variable, uniform-distribution

Suppose we have a uniform random variable $U$
  which is defined on the $[0,1]$
  interval. Consider the transformation:$$X=k\times \log(U)$$

How would I go about calculating the interval on which $X$
  is defined?

I guess on one hand, the upper limit would be given as $k\times \log(1)=0$
 . However, I cannot evaluate $k\times \log(0)$.
  Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Intervall should $(-\infty,0]$, Since the right limit of log at zero is $-\infty$

Edited due to dsaxton's comment:
Note that the probability that U takes any value $c \in [0,1]$ is 0, or in math notation $P(U=c)=0$ for every $c \in [0,1]$

Why do we take limits, (do we?)?
First, let me remark that log is bijective strictly increasing function from $(0,1] \to (-\infty,0]$. Using some math one could define the continuous extension of in zero log to be $log(0):= -\infty$
However, in that case, $P(X=-\infty)=P(U=0)=0$, and the value $-\infty$ won't play a role.

However, to determine the image of $X$, we employ the range of log on $(0,1]$ being $(-\infty,0]$. In both intervals, and in the determination of the image of log on $(0,1]$ limits are involved

Comment: Im not sure I follow..U does take on a value of 0 with probability density =1. This is not the case of the transformation of U

Comment: Thanks for your response, but why do we evaluate the limit of the function at the value instead of the function at the value?

Comment: @ChinG The density of $U$ is defined at one (entirely arbitrarily it turns out) but $P(U = 0) = 0$ so you never have to worry about $\log(0)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lucid explanation. One final question: why are we involving limits of the function at the value here instead of evaluating the function at the value itself?